# Prevent merging of branch conditionally based on label

Tags: github, github-actions

My team uses private branches which do not have access to Draft Pull Requests, but I would still at least like a way to prevent merging pull requests while they have a custom label applied to them such as "Draft" or "WIP".

Is there a way to establish a **custom** required status check that checks for that label or uses a GitHub action to invalidate the PR until the label is removed or something like that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you don't have draft pull requests available, I assume you don't have branch protection rules as well. Therefore, you cannot really *enforce* what you describe in your question. However, it is possible to give some graphical hints to make the users aware that the PR is a draft.

This can be done with a workflow in [GitHub Actions](https://docs.github.com/en/actions). You need to add the `opened`, `labeled` and `unlabeled` type on the [`pull_request` trigger](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#pull_request) in order to run the workflow when the PR gets created or when labels get changed. Afterwards, you can define a job which only runs when the custom label (e.g. `draft`) is present and just run [`exit 1` to fail](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/creating-actions/setting-exit-codes-for-actions#about-exit-codes) the check.

*Here is the complete workflow (e.g. **check-draft.yml**):*

```yaml
name: Check Draft

on:
  pull_request:
#    branches:
#      - main
    types:
      - opened
      - labeled
      - unlabeled

jobs:
  fail-for-draft:
    if: contains(github.event.pull_request.labels.*.name, 'draft')
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Fail if PR is a draft
        run: |
          echo "This PR is currently a draft."
          exit 1
```

*Failed check with `draft` label on PR:* (Note that even though the merge button is grey, the PR can actually be merged if no branch protection rules are set.)

[image: fail]

*Successful run with no `draft` label on PR:*

[image: success]

Comment: I could not have asked for a more comprehensive solution. Thank you!!

Answer (score 3):

Moving the condition inside the steps will show green check✅ instead of being shown as skipped

```
name: Check Draft

on:
  pull_request:
    types:
      - opened
      - labeled
      - unlabeled

jobs:
  fail-for-draft:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Fail if PR is a draft
        if: contains(github.event.pull_request.labels.*.name, 'draft') # Move the condition to here
        run: |
          echo "This PR is currently a draft."
          exit 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Just want to add something to this

In case someone has a bug when we update new things to the pull request, the checks will run again but it is stuck at

```
Expected — Waiting for status to be reported
```

We may have to add some extra events

```
---
name: 'Check Mergable by label ✅'

on:
  pull_request:
    types:
      - opened
      - reopened
      - synchronize
      - edited
      - labeled
      - unlabeled

jobs:
  fail-by-label:
    if: contains(github.event.pull_request.labels.*.name, 'do not merge')
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Fail if PR is labeled "do not merge"
        run: |
          echo "This PR is labeled as do not merge!"
          exit 1
```